# Exchange 2013 Mailbox rights - how to prevent emails from being deleted

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013

I have a mailbox I would like to prevent users from deleting mails in, it is a shared mailbox on exchange 2013. At one stage the mailbox was converted from a shared folder to a shared mailbox, but some emails are going missing.

Is there a way that exchange can grant some users delete rights and some not.

Comment: You could enable litigation hold but that would prevent all users from deleting anything.

Comment: Thanks litigation hold is perfect, another option for this is to search the dumpster in exchange using this command. Search-Mailbox <mailbox name> SearchDumpsterOnly -deletecontent